# How do I select each row from a table, ordering them by the most "recent (timestamp)" associated row in join table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with `quotes`. Each quote can get `feedbacks` (quote has many feedbacks).

I would like to select * quotes (distinct of course), ordering them by the most recent `submitted_at` date from the feedbacks table descending, for each quote:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pHTQzkWMYND8CGJcAiu2JC/3

I have played around with a `PARTITION`-clause, but did not manage to succeed.

The expected outcome of from the query in the db-fiddle example is:

```
3   2017-03-24T00:00:00.000Z    Cata
1   2017-01-02T00:00:00.000Z    Radu
4   2017-04-20T00:00:00.000Z    David
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT quotes.id, f.submitted_at, buyer_name
FROM quotes INNER JOIN (
    SELECT quote_id, MAX(submitted_at) AS submitted_at 
    FROM feedbacks 
    GROUP BY quote_id
) f ON quotes.id = f.quote_id
ORDER BY f.submitted_at DESC
```

**demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pHTQzkWMYND8CGJcAiu2JC/4

Answer (score 0):

fiddle link was changed so you need below by using `row_number()`

```
select q.id,f.submitted_at, q.buyer_name from 
(
 select *,row_number()over(partition by quote_id order by submitted_at desc) rn
from feedbacks 
) f
join  quotes q on f.quote_id=q.id
where f.rn=1
```

[demo link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pHTQzkWMYND8CGJcAiu2JC/3)

```
id  submitted_at                buyer_name
1   2017-03-20T00:00:00.000Z    Radu
3   2017-04-25T00:00:00.000Z    Cata
4   2017-01-10T00:00:00.000Z    David
```

Comment: Do we really need to partition in this scenario, why can't we just join the two tables and get the max date from feed backs?

Comment: @AjanBalakumaran that is another approch

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a sub query, your expected outcome is straight forward.

```
SELECT
quotes.ID,max(feedbacks.submitted_at) as submitted_at,buyer_name
FROM quotes 
INNER JOIN feedbacks
ON quotes.id = feedbacks.quote_id
group by quotes.ID,buyer_name
```